# What is the difference between function.length and arguments.length in JS

Tags: javascript

I encountered this question in edabit :

Create a function that returns the number of arguments it was called with.

I tried to google the answer but I found 2 ways to create such function but it is confusing.

For examples,

```
numArgs() ➞ 0

numArgs("foo") ➞ 1

numArgs("foo", "bar") ➞ 2

numArgs(true, false) ➞ 2

numArgs({}) ➞ 1
```

As stated in the title of my question, what is the difference between function.length and arguments.length

If I create like :

```
function args(){
  return arguments.length;
}
```

I get the result

but what is the difference when I do args.length instead?

Comment: The `length` property of a function is how many *declared parameters* it has. `arguments` on the other hand gives you the *total number of arguments it was called with*. So `function f(a, b) {}` will have `f.length === 2` but you can call it as `f(1)` or `f(1, 2, 3)` which means `arguments.length` would be `1` or `3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many
> arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.
> ... By contrast, `arguments.length` is local to a function and
> provides the number of arguments actually passed to the function.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Comment: so arguments.length is used within the curly brackets and length property is used for defined function to get the number of its arguments?

Comment: The `.length` property on the function itself tells you how many arguments appear in the function declaration. The `.length` property of the `arguments` object tells you how many *actual* parameters were passed on a particular call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines a function which is called "args" that accepts/handles no arguments.

That function returns the "length" (count) of its *received* *arguments*, which would depend on how many arguments (if any) where passed to it when it is called.

The "length" (count) of its *declared* *arguments* is 0, as its declaration does not specify any arguments.